# XCP-XAPI on public server

Tags: iptables, xen

How can i solve this?

i am having a XCP_XAPI on a public server.But when accessed through browser its showing "**Developer XenAPI viewer**" .

how can i hide this page from appearing or allow access from a particular ip.With out causing any problem with managing through XEN CENTRE.
i tried

> iptables -t filter -I INPUT -p tcp ! -s my-ip --dport 80 -j REJECT
>
> iptables -t filter -I INPUT -p tcp ! -s my-ip --dport 443 -j REJECT

even though it solved  the problem,but i can not connect through XEN Centre.How can i solve it.Without affecting the webserver running inside those vms which listen on port 80.Which actually shares bridge network with host IP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may be blocking localhost from accessing xen from connecting to port 80.

try

iptables -I INPUT -s 127.0.0.1 -j ACCEPT

iptables -I INPUT -s ip-of-xcp-host -j ACCEPT